# Teamviewer not remembering Teamviewer account

Tags: 14.04, wine, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I'm using Teamviewer for my remote desktop needs. On any Linux version of teamviewer, it uses Wine as a compatibility back-end (presumably so the dev's don't have to support another OS). It works relatively fine, however, one problem is pretty big - my Teamviewer account is not remembered between sessions, despite using the "Remember me" checkbox. This means that I have to login to my Teamviewer account on every startup, in order to connect to my other computers.

Is there any way to fix this? I doubt this is the intended behavior.

uname -a:
`Linux hostname 3.13.0-34-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 13 15:49:09 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux`